# How to round up a value with any decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, rounding, python-3.3

I want to make the value always round up no matter what it is, so example:

```
Strength = 16.33333
```

What would I use on that to make it (No matter what it equals) round up to the next whole number?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I got it fixed now.

Answer (score 14):

Simply use the `ceil` function:

```
>>> import math
>>> a = math.ceil(16.33333)
>>> a
17
>>> a = math.ceil(17)
>>> a
17
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm finding it hard to implement this into some work I have to produce. I have to role to random numbers and then additionally after round them up. So I wouldn't know for example what the number was to be able to put '== 17'.

Comment: You don't have to put `== 17`! It was just a way to tell you the result of the `ceil` function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing that:

```
a if a.is_integer() else int(a)+1
```

Comment: It wouldn't work on integers formated as float. e.g.: a = 20/2

Answer (score 1):

Hey I previously answered this question but it did not really help too much. Today I realized you can still round an integer/float up to the next number without importing math. Just do this.

```
round(number+0.5)
```

No matter what you enter even if it is a whole number or a float it will always round up to the next number.

I usually do not like to use imports if it is possible to avoid them! Just another way to round up to the whole number with the `math.ceil()` method. Hope this helps!

Comment: It wouldn't work on integers: `round(17 + 0.5)` is `18`, not `17`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_up(number_):
    rounded = int(number_) if round(number_) == number_ else int(number_)+1
    return rounded
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way

```
def round_up(number, downBelowZero = False):
    if(str(number).find(".")>-1):
        x = str(number).split(".")
        if(downBelowZero and number<0):
            return int(x[0])-1
        else:
            return int(x[0])+1
    
    else:
        return int(number)
```

Comment: can't we use `math function` which will handle all the edge cases implicitly.